# Is it possible to accessing Pervasive sql database via spring boot?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, pervasive

it's possible to accessing Pervasive sql database via spring boot

Comment: You can as long as there's a type IV JDBC driver for Pervasive available.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Spring Boot but it looks like it supports JDBC and Pervasive offers a JDBC interface.  Documentation for the Actian Zen (current, as of March 2021, version of Pervasive SQL) JDBC is available at https://docs.actian.com/zen/v14/index.html#page/jdbc/jdbc_gd.htm